# Intermittent problems connecting to wifi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am hoping for some help with troubleshooting steps on this one. I am having intermittent problems connecting to the internet on multiple laptops. I ran ipconfig and everything looks okay. I did a ping to 8.8.8.8 and I got intermittent request timeouts. I then ran ping against my default gateway which is also the wifi router and got a similar problem. so it appears the problem is with the router. I tried resetting it by pulling the power but I am still having the same problem. I was hoping for some help with any next steps for troubleshooting this.

Here is a sample output of my ping to my router:

```
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=3196ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=1817ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=470ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=198ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=73ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=278ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=265ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=163ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=271ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=3020ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.4.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
```

You can see that it is good most of the time, but then it will get really slow, up to 3+ seconds, and then it will timeout, then be good again.

Comment: Try updating the firmware to see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: have you changed channels to rule out interference? Also, whats the make/model of the WiFi router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tim_Stewart was headed in the right direction with interference. It lead me to thinking about how I have several wifi extenders throughout the house. I tried unplugging one of them and the issue went away. I don't know too much about the extenders I have, but I assume that they usually automatically select a channel that would not interfere with the others around them. They all worked great until the other day. I am assuming that one of them got messed up and selected an interfering channel. Anyway now I will look into the extenders more to soon how/if I can manually configure the channels.